# Using XML instead of an Java Class

Tags: java, android, xml, setcontentview

I need help. Actually I use this to setContentView to the class that handles my onDraw.

```
canvasView = new CanvasView(DrawingActivity.this, firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Rooms").child(bundle.getString("pushID")).child("pos"), 1080, 1920);
    setContentView(canvasView);
```

But I would like to use a XML because I can better design it then. **Is there a way to see a XML instead of this?** The problem is that i need this class because it is managing what i draw on a canvas. So i cant just do `setContentView(R.layout.Xml);` i guess.

**Thank you !**

Comment: you can put a custom view in an xml layout and call setContentView, the problem is that the constructor that will be called will be the one with 2 parameters (Context and AttributeSet), you can't pass all those arguments in the constructor. however, you can get a reference of the view and call a setter after setContentView. what is that CanvasView?

Comment: CanvasView is my Class that creating a new Canvas base of the last two parameters (int width, int height) it creates bitmaps and writing the points i draw to firebase. @lelloman

Comment: My base for the CanvasView was this old Activity Drawing Firebase example : https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/drawing/DrawingView.java